# Configuring Sun server JRE for Ubuntu 10.04 on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, ubuntu-10.04

I've just created a brand new Ubuntu 10.04 Amazon EC2 image that I plan to use as a java application server.

I can log in successfully by SSH.

I want to install the Sun server JRE but have a couple of questions:

- Access to the "multiverse" doesn't
  seem to be enabled in the EC2
  instance - how to do this?
- What is the best strategy to avoid reinstalling whenever I start a new
  instance?

Can any experienced Ubuntu wizard give me some specific advice on how to get this set up in the best possible way?

Comment: p.s. I've tried adding "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner" to my sources.list but it hasn't helped....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I figured out an approach that works:

```
Edit sources.list file:
  sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list

Add lines:
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

Update source list:
  sudo apt-get update

Install Sun Java JRE:
  sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```