# Using apt-get in Linux EC2 Micro Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, user-permissions

I am trying to install apt on my Linux EC2 Micro Instance. I am trying to do as it is mentioned in the first answer of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/160689/configuring-sun-server-jre-for-ubuntu-10-04-on-amazon-ec2). But when I try to edit and save the sources.list file, I am getting the following error.
**"/etc/apt/sources.list" E212: Can't open file for writing**

I have logged in as ec2-user and changed to root using sudo su -. But Still I am not able to save the file. Can you please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do a

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

? Should work this way. If it does not allow you, maybe you're not in the sudoers file. To include yourself, do

```
sudo visudo
```

(that should get you in a vi editor with the sudoers config file open). You can edit using the "I" key to start adding text, but first move the cursor just below where it says

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

From there, as I say, press I and write:

```
ec2-user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To sabe your changes, press "ESC", ":" and "w", and ENTER. To quit, "ESC", ":", "q".

After editing sudoers, you should be able to try again the

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And edit the file normally. Should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestions. When I tried to do save, I got [ Error writing /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory ].

Comment: Are you sure you're using a Ubuntu/Debian instance? Maybe you've set up a RPM based distribution. In that case that file wouldn't be there because the package manager is not apt-get. Instead you should use yum, for example.

Comment: Hey thanks, yea i was able to install using yum :)

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not all GNU/Linux distributions use apt-get. Your micro instance is probably not Debian-based, and does not use apt-get to provide packages.